# Why does object with a string prints as null?

Tags: java

Probably a noob question but why this code prints null?

```
public class Bug1 { 
    private String s;
    public void Bug1() {
        s = "hello";
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug1 x = new Bug1();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `void` keyword here, making your 'constructor' a method (which is never called), so the `String` `s` is never initialised. Object references at class level will be `null` by default.

```
public void Bug1() {
```

to fix, change to:

```
public Bug1() {
```

Constructors don't have return types.

Comment: Worth mentioning that, when a constructor is not defined for a class, a default constructor is created that invokes the superclass constructor (Object) which does nothing relevant to the question. Similarly, the string is automatically initialized by default to `null` if it is not set in a constructor. This is a good case for having `final` instance variables, but now I'm getting too advanced :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Bug1 { 
    private String s;
    public Bug1() {
        s = "hello";
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug1 x = new Bug1();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

You defined Bug1 as a method instead of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined a method and not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [constructors in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Here's what you should've done:

```
public class Bug1 { 
    private String s;
    public Bug1() { //Parameterless constructor
        s = "hello";
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug1 x = new Bug1();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

constructor has no return type all the times in java.